# Crop Image From User Input

Tags: c#, user-interface, image-processing

I'm building a c# app to take photos of visitors for ID badges. I have found a c# wrapper for web cams so can take a snap shot easily, however I need to set the images to a certain number of pixels ideally with the persons head filling most of the area.

I imagine the best way to do this is to allow the end user to drag out a rectangle over the initial image with fixed x and y ratio covering the persons face. This would crop the image and do any resolution adjustment necessary.

Does anyone know of an example similar to this? I think I know how to do the rectangle and get my co-ordinates for the image cropping apart from fixing an x and y ratio. Obviously an example would be quicker than trying to write my own.

Answer (score 0):

As of .Net 3.0, System.Windows.Media.Imaging provides a `CroppedBitmap` class that inherits from `BitmapSource`.  Its constructor takes a `BitmapSource` and an `Int32Rect`.  If you pass it your original image and your rect, it will return a cropped image as a `BitmapSource`.